Export GRBL Axis positions for LCD
I've been trying to export the real-time current axis position (x, y) of GRBL firmware to an LCD display, but I cannot find where to export this from. I need to export it directly from the GRBL code. Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?
I`ve been trying to export from Planner.c, but doesn't work.
